# How to select multiple images with same class as another page

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, selector

this is my first time posting so hopefully i don't get it too wrong.

i am trying to find a way to select images to give them a radius and need a bit of help deciphering the css selectors i need to use.

the company i am doing this for is using a wordpress site, with plugins and i have no access to do a quick fix like changing the class in the php files.

i can select all images individually no problem by using the inspect element and copying the css selectors.

when i do this for an individual item my css looks something like this

```
div.content-box-column:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) img {}
```

for the first image within the container and the selector for the last is something like this.

```
div.fusion-column:nth-child(7) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > img:nth-child(1)
```

i know its probably super easy but i cant see how i could i apply this as a single selector within the range of images

any help is greatly appreciated

Edit: as Requested a snippet of what the rendered html looks like.

[Rendered Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIXEJ.png)

Edit: as Requested the Html rendered by WordPress

```html
<div class="fusion-content-boxes content-boxes columns row fusion-columns-3 fusion-columns-total-6 fusion-content-boxes-1 content-boxes-icon-on-top content-left" data-animationoffset="100%" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:60px;"><style type="text/css">.fusion-content-boxes-1 .heading .content-box-heading {color:#212934;}
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover .heading .content-box-heading,
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover .heading .heading-link .content-box-heading,
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover .heading .content-box-heading,
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover .heading .heading-link .content-box-heading,
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more,
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more::after,
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more::before,
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .fusion-read-more:hover:after,
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .fusion-read-more:hover:before,
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .fusion-read-more:hover,
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more,
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more::after,
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more::before,
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover .icon .circle-no,
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .heading .heading-link:hover .content-box-heading {
                        color: #125f31;
                    }
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover .icon .circle-no {
                        color: #125f31 !important;
                    }.fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box.link-area-box-hover .fusion-content-box-button {background: #125f31;color: #fff;}.fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box.link-area-box-hover .fusion-content-box-button .fusion-button-text {color: #fff;}
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover .heading .icon > span {
                        background-color: #125f31 !important;
                    }
                    .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover .heading .icon > span {
                        border-color: #125f31 !important;
                    }</style><div class="fusion-column content-box-column content-box-column content-box-column-1 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 fusion-content-box-hover content-box-column-first-in-row"><div class="col content-box-wrapper content-wrapper link-area-box icon-hover-animation-fade" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);" data-animationoffset="100%"><div class="heading heading-with-icon icon-left"><div aria-hidden="true" class="image"><img src="https://www.nsg.ie/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Leaner2.jpg" alt="" data-pagespeed-url-hash="163116447" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" width="300" height="250"></div></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div><div class="content-container" style="color:#ffffff;">
<p class="sale_boxTwo"><a href="https://www.nsg.ie/product-category/wall-mirrors/">Wall Mirrors</a></p>
</div></div></div><div class="fusion-column content-box-column content-box-column content-box-column-2 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 fusion-content-box-hover "><div class="col content-box-wrapper content-wrapper link-area-box icon-hover-animation-fade" style="background-color:rgba(96,125,139,0);" data-animationoffset="100%"><div class="heading heading-with-icon icon-left"><div aria-hidden="true" class="image"><img src="https://www.nsg.ie/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/ShelvesrightSize.jpg" alt="" data-pagespeed-url-hash="2246665079" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" width="300" height="250"></div></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div><div class="content-container" style="color:#ffffff;">
<p class="sale_boxTwo"><a href="https://www.nsg.ie/product-category/glass-shelves/">Glass Shelves</a></p>
</div></div></div><div class="fusion-column content-box-column content-box-column content-box-column-3 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 fusion-content-box-hover content-box-column-last-in-row"><div class="col content-box-wrapper content-wrapper link-area-box icon-hover-animation-fade" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);" data-animationoffset="100%"><div class="heading heading-with-icon icon-left"><div aria-hidden="true" class="image"><img src="https://www.nsg.ie/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/FittingsRightSize.png" alt="" data-pagespeed-url-hash="1918251973" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" width="300" height="250"></div></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div><div class="content-container" style="color:#ffffff;">
<p class="sale_boxTwo"><a href="https://www.nsg.ie/product-category/fittings/">Fittings</a></p>
</div></div></div><div class="fusion-column content-box-column content-box-column content-box-column-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 fusion-content-box-hover content-box-column-first-in-row"><div class="col content-box-wrapper content-wrapper link-area-box icon-hover-animation-fade" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);" data-animationoffset="100%"><div class="heading heading-with-icon icon-left"><div aria-hidden="true" class="image"><img src="https://www.nsg.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Stove-Glass-Glass-Hearths-300x250.png" alt="" data-pagespeed-url-hash="1873671197" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" width="300" height="250"></div></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div><div class="content-container" style="color:#ffffff;">
<p class="sale_boxTwo"><a href="https://www.nsg.ie/product-category/stove-products/">Stove Products</a></p>
</div></div></div><div class="fusion-column content-box-column content-box-column content-box-column-5 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 fusion-content-box-hover "><div class="col content-box-wrapper content-wrapper link-area-box icon-hover-animation-fade" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);" data-animationoffset="100%"><div class="heading heading-with-icon icon-left"><div aria-hidden="true" class="image"><img src="https://www.nsg.ie/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/acrylic.jpg" alt="Clear Polycarbonate" data-pagespeed-url-hash="3135282522" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" width="300" height="250"></div></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div><div class="content-container" style="color:#ffffff;">
<p class="sale_boxTwo"><a href="https://www.nsg.ie/product-category/polycarbonate-sheets/">Polycarbonate</a></p>
</div></div></div><div class="fusion-column content-box-column content-box-column content-box-column-6 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 fusion-content-box-hover content-box-column-last content-box-column-last-in-row"><div class="col content-box-wrapper content-wrapper link-area-box icon-hover-animation-fade" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);" data-animationoffset="100%"><div class="heading heading-with-icon icon-left"><div aria-hidden="true" class="image"><img src="https://www.nsg.ie/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/SkewedScreen.jpg" alt="" data-pagespeed-url-hash="1973181063" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" width="300" height="250"></div></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div><div class="content-container" style="color:#ffffff;">
<p class="sale_boxTwo"><a href="https://www.nsg.ie/product-category/protective-screen/">Protective Screens</a></p>
</div></div></div><style type="text/css">
                        .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .heading-link:hover .icon i.circle-yes,
                        .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box:hover .heading-link .icon i.circle-yes,
                        .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover .heading .icon i.circle-yes,
                        .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover .heading .icon i.circle-yes {
                            background-color: #125f31 !important;
                            border-color: #125f31 !important;
                        }</style><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div></div>
```

Comment: Welcome :) I'm not sure what's the right selector from your question but you can start with `div.fusion-column img` and see if you need to tight it.

Comment: Hey there, can you show us a sample of what the rendered HTML looks like? I can glean parts of it from the two selectors you've provided but a more complete structure would help.

Comment: Please share HTML code!

Comment: i don't have access to the php files which are rendering the html as it is hosted externally. if it would be of help i could share the rendered html ? ill will edit my question with said html concerning the container i am trying to select.

Answer (score -1):

If you just simply want to select all `img` tags with CSS

```
img {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: The problem i'm having isn't selecting all images its selecting the particular range above. nth-child(2)-nth-child(7) img. any ideas on how to do this ?